# Vertical Scrollbar disappears in absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position

**EDIT** : Added : http://jsfiddle.net/bfNzH/1/

My Html is structured like so :

```
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">left bar</div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="topbar">topbar</div>
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div>..some stuff</div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="th1">Col1</th>
                            <th>Col2</th>
                            <th>Col3</th>
                            <th>Col4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
 body {
    height : 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 0;
    right : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
}
.left {
    height : 100%;
    position : absolute;
    width : 50px;
    overflow : hidden;
    border-right : 1px solid black;
}
.right {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 50px;
    bottom : 0;
    right : 0;
    //border : 1px solid red;
}
.topbar {
    height : 20px;
    display : table;
    width : 100%;
    border-bottom : 1px solid green;
}
.header {
    height : 30px;
    display : table;
    width : 100%;
}
.content {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    position : absolute;
    overflow : auto;
    top : 50px;
    bottom : 0px;
    border-top : 1px solid yellow;
    border-bottom : 1px solid yellow;
}
.th1 {
    width : 50%;
}
table {
    width : 100%;
}
th, tr {
    text-align : center;
}
```

If my table has a lot of rows, then the content goes beyond the page and a scrollbar appears.. but this is what happens to the scrollbar :

[image: Error image]

I understand the since I have absolutely positioned the elements and added a `top` to it so the vertical scrollbar has shifted by that amount.

**I'd like one of 2 solutions :**

1. The scrollbar comes to the content element
2. Scrollbar comes to the table body.

I can achieve the second by adding a `display : block` to `tbody` but then it screws up the alignment very badly. Observe:

[image: Blown up table]

Comment: jsFiddle or CodePen? Please

Comment: decrease width from 100% to somewhat 98% then you'll find there scrollbar.

Comment: @C-Link: You mean height? But that's a hack. Will need to do it through js.

Comment: `body { min-height: 100%; }` ? Remove `.right { bottom: 0; }` ? Really need a fiddle to play with to be honest.

Comment: Alright.. Making one.

Comment: It looks like you have a div positioned on top of your div with the scrollbar. That could be causing the issue

Comment: @ColinMcGrath I think that's just the Windows system clock ;-)

Comment: @gvee Hehe whoops. Thats what I get for being Unix based for so long

Comment: you have a lot of un-closed `div`s in your markup. Iv'e tried your markup (after fixing the `div`s) + your CSS in IE10 with WIN7, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the `height: 100%;` from the content block, the scrollbar shows it's real height:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfNzH/4/

Comment: Thank god. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "Overflow" attribute in your **Content** div which might be set to hidden with specific height set to it.

Comment: The css provided is the one on the site

Comment: added jsfiddle to question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS property: "height:100%" for ".content".

I think that you should use a debugger tool in your browser. Firebug for mozilla and for Chrome you can use the default debugger tool. Hope you can also better solve your issue next time.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks.. I already got my answer. And I do use dev tools and a dev tool won't tell me where to fix things.